# C++ - Cin.fail when space on begining

Tags: c++

I need help with cin.fail when it starts with a space.

This is what I mean.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    char b[80];
    int e,d,v,m=0;

    for(int i=0;i<80;i++)
    {
        b[i]=0;
    }

    cout << "Insert number in binary:" << endl;
    cin >> b;

    v=0;
    for(int i=0;i<80;i++)
    {
        if(b[i]=='1' || b[i]=='0' || b[i]=='\n')
        {
        v++;
        }
        else if(b[i]!=0 || b[i]!='\0' || b[i]==' ')
        {
            cout << "Error" << endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }

    e=v-1;
    d=0;
    m=0;
    for(int i=0;i<v;i++)
    {
      m=(b[i]-48)*(pow(2,e));
      d=d+m;
      e=e-1;
    }

    cout << "His number in decimal: "<< d << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When there is something like 1010 it OK, it will give me number.
If it contains other number - 2,3 etc.. it will fail, its OK
But when it get something like _101010 .. programm will still proceed and it will give me number, but I need it to fail. So I need something like .. when b contains 1 0 or \n, programm will continue, otherwise it will fail. But when I put in \n like

`if(b[i]=='1' || b[i]=='0' || b[i]=='\n')` - its not working .. I mean, programm fails in any case ...

Sorry for asking on this "stupid" question, but I am doing it for hours and still didnt figure it out .. Thanks guys.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You aren't even using `cin` anywhere in the code you posted, and we don't know what `b`, `i`, and `v` are or what they have to do with what you're asking.

Comment: I understand you. I mean. I have on cin decimal Binary number. Like 010101 and at Cout I transfer it into decimal .. so for example, when u put into cin 1100, cout will go out with 12. When u put into cin 123, cout will fail with some error message "Nespravny vstup" because 2 and 3 are not from binary numbers. And I need program to fail if somebody will put space at the start of inputting cin .. Like .. _0101 .. In this case I need program to fail ..

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok I editted it, put in complete program.Hopefully u will understand me now.

Answer (score 0):

`cin >> b;` will skip leading whitespace and then read the next word. That's how it is designed.

If you want to read an entire line of input, use `getline` instead.

It will also be much easier, and a lot safer, if you read into a `std::string` instead of a fixed size `char b[80];`. If you ever happen to read more than 80 characters into that, you're toast.